# Mailbird IMAP issue

Tags: imap, email

I have IMAP set up and went through my inbox and archived a bunch of messages. My Mailbird says I am at INBOX 0....yet when I go online I have 14 messages still in my inbox? Any ideas why it is not syncing my changes back to the web?

Comment: Is it working the other way round, i.e. syncing messages from the web to the client?

Comment: Yes, my inbox has messages online, like with OWA. But my desktop application isnt notifying me or has this messages in inbox.

Comment: This isn't a programming question, is it? Might want to move it to superuser.com.

Comment: Actually you are right, didn't knew about superuser.com ... thank you very much, I will try to find my answer there.